# Is it possible to create a private application available only for specific users ?

Tags: facebook, private

Basically, we want to create an application for facebook.. where users that have an account on our system are able to install our facebook application.  We do not want this application to all facebook users. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now in for installing Facebook application. you cant restrict users from installing your app in Page Tab. But you can restrict your content, to which user/pageid you want show.

1) Restrict on User basis.

You put an put `if()` condition to check whether the user is in your database. if yes then only show the content else  you show a message that you don't have permission

2) Restrict on Page .

If you want to restrict your app to accessible only in some of Facebook pages , then you can use signed request to get page id and check this page id is registered with your system or not. Then show your app content on this condition.

Comment: I see. I dont have a facebook account so I cant tell. But say we want to have items show up in a facebook feed. That we from our application would push to facebook for the user that installs our application. Is this possible ?

Comment: yes, you can post content to user feed. Your app will require `publish_stream` permission from user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

1. Go to Settings of application.
2. Choose 'Basic' tab.
3. For 'Sandbox Mode:' choose 'enable'.

Now your application is close for all users.
To take access to your application for some users make next steps:

1. In settings of application choose tab 'Roles'.
2. Add UID of user in one of category: Administrators, Developers, Testers.

Now this user have access to your application.

Comment: You should also mention that this will limit the “reach” of stuff done by your app on Facebook (wall posts, …) – they will not show up for “everyone”, even with appropriate privacy settings, while the app is in sandbox mode … so one has to consider first if this is the desired behavior.

Comment: So im not talking about a sandbox environment. A production app, that can only be installed and used by facebook users that also have an account in our system. Is this doable ?

Comment: Ok. If you wanna a production app with restricted access then the answer of Abhishek is for you.

Answer (score -3):

For example you can connect to database where are stored user accounts and make authentication process.